# How to change size of Nav bar

Tags: html, css

All the questions I've looked at refer to WordPress or Bootstrap (what is that?) nav bars, I have made mine using CSS.

I would like to make my nav bar bigger so that it's easier for mobile users to click the correct link. I've tried using the `height: px;` but all that did was push the text below further down.

What do I use to change the size of the buttons themselves? included my CSS below.

```css
html{background:gray;}
ul {
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
}
li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0
}
li a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #111;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="/AboutUs.html">About</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="/ContactUs.html">Contact</a>
  </li>

</ul>
```

Comment: Can you post your html or a link to it too?

Comment: By the way bootstrap is a javascript /css library that dynamically resizes things to make it easier for viewers on all screen sizes (including mobile).

Comment: @nhouser9 Ah I see, I don't know any JavaScript so avoid it when possible until I learn more. The link to the page : http://www.trinity-international.com/index.html

Comment: I took the liberty of making your code into a snippet for handiness, but had to add a background color to show the navbar. You can roll back if you wanted.

Comment: @Gg8 See my answer now that you posted your html. If it doesn't work, let me know and I'll take another look. Even though it was for some reason downvoted twice...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to make the text itself larger you can use the `font-size` property.

Answer (score 1):

<sup>Please note I have added backgrounds in order to display the navbar, and are not required in production</sup>

You are OK to use the `ul` and `li` elements within your code. In order to make the navbar appear 'taller', you would need to set both the `height` of the `ul` element itself, as well as the child `li`. A quick demo has been provided below.

I have given the height of the ul element 100px, although this value can be changed to your preference. Note you may also want to change `line-height` property of your `a` elements to suit this.

```css
html,body {
  background: gray;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
ul {
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  list-style-type: none;
  background: dimgray;
  height: 100px;     /*          <-- change this line*/
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
}
li a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  background: lightgray;
  line-height: 100px; /*          <-- change this line*/
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-right: 50px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
li a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #111;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="/AboutUs.html">About</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="/ContactUs.html">Contact</a>
  </li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

> What do I use to change the size of the buttons themselves?

Add more padding!  Take a look-see.

```css
body {background-color: gray;}

ul {
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
}
li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 2em;  /* bigger button?  add more padding! */
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0
}
li a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #111;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="/AboutUs.html">About</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="/ContactUs.html">Contact</a>
  </li>

</ul>
```

There are many ways to increase the size of the link.  This is just one way.  jbutler's answer is a good way too.  It just depends on what exactly you want it to do.

Hope this helps.